# Use my index page as a different page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I understand there's been a number of similar questions about this subject in the past years therefore I will try my best to be as descriptive as possible so my query can be understood from the get go. I am working on my WordPress site via my local machine, rolling on XAMPP and using Visual Studio Code as my code editor. I have my index.php set as my home page, this is the beginning of the code for such page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (!post_password_required($post)) { ?>

    <?php
    //get theme option
    $options = get_option('sample_theme_options');
    //echo "wow" . $options['sometext'];
    ?>

    <script>
        var bgvidsrc = "<?php echo $options['bgv1']; ?>";
        var bgvidsrc2 = "<?php echo $options['bgv2']; ?>";
        var bgvidsrc3 = "<?php echo $options['bgv3']; ?>";
        var bgvidsrc4 = "<?php echo $options['bgv4']; ?>";
        var bgvidsrc5 = "<?php echo $options['bgv5']; ?>";
        var bgvidsrc6 = "<?php echo $options['bgv6']; ?>";
    </script>

    <?php $path = get_template_directory_uri() . "/"; ?>

    <!-- <body onload="init()"> -->

    <body class="loading">



        <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
```

My aim is to use this page as a different page which I want to rename as architects.php and access it via a new index page I am going to create, which will contain 4 buttons as anchors, and one of those will take the visitor to the new architects.php (the other 3 buttons will be for other 3 categories as pages which I will spin up too).
I need to maintain the design for the new architects.php as it contains animations I want to display, just not as the index page but as its unique page (architects.php)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename `architects.php` will be fine, though you may want to prefix the filename with `template-` for clarity. The key is to add a template header to the file:

```php
/**
 * Template name: Architects
 */
```

Adding that header will add "Architects" to the dropdown in the Template meta box on the "Add New Page" screen.

Official doc:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Comment: Hi Caleb, to which file do I need to add that template header please? will it be to the index.php which I have already renamed as architects.php?

Comment: Add to `architects.php`.

Comment: Hi again Caleb, thank you for your comments. My new index looks like this - just testing at the mo:

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>

<a href="wp-content\themes\ourwe\architects.php"><h1>test</h1></a>

Comment: And my architects.php like this:

Comment: <?php

/** * Template Name: Architects * * package WordPress * subpackage ourwe * @since ourwe */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (!post_password_required($post)) { ?>

 <?php
 //get theme option
 $options = get_option('sample_theme_options');
 //echo "wow" . $options['sometext'];
 ?>

 <script>
  var bgvidsrc = "<?php echo $options['bgv1']; ?>";
  var bgvidsrc2 = "<?php echo $options['bgv2']; ?>";
  var bgvidsrc3 = "<?php echo $options['bgv3']; ?>";
  var bgvidsrc4 = "<?php echo $options['bgv4']; ?>";
  var bgvidsrc5 = "<?php echo $options['bgv5']; ?>";
  etc etc

Comment: when I click on the button on my new index.php, it throws a fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cubetechstaging\wp-content\themes\ourwe\architects.php  - why could this be??

Comment: You definitely do not want to link to a template file. It seems like you do not understand basic WordPress theme development, and how to create pages in WordPress. Recommend you do a Google search for WordPress tutorial on creating pages, and then come back here once you've mastered that.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and yes, I'm pretty new to WP and its "mazey" theme development. So, do you mean I need to create the page using the pages section in the dashboard and then link that to my index and bring all the code I want to retain in to the page I have created in the dashboard?

Comment: Yes, you’ll create pages in WP admin, and assign the Architects page template as needed.

Comment: ok got it working in the end, all sorted, thanks mate